# How can I get LifecycleOwner reference in RecyclerView.Adapter?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

At present, I use `mLifecycleOwner = mContext as LifecycleOwner` to get `LifecycleOwner`, it can work, but I don't think it's a good code.

How can I get `LifecycleOwner` from `ListAdapter`?

```
class VoiceAdapters (private val aHomeViewModel: HomeViewModel, private val mPlay: PlayInterface):
        ListAdapter<MVoice, VoiceAdapters.VoiceViewHolder>(MVoiceDiffCallback()) {

    private lateinit var mContext: Context
    private lateinit var mLifecycleOwner:LifecycleOwner

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VoiceViewHolder {
        mContext = parent.context
        mLifecycleOwner = mContext as LifecycleOwner

        return VoiceViewHolder(
            LayoutVoiceItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false).also {               
               it.lifecycleOwner = mLifecycleOwner
               it.aHomeViewModel = aHomeViewModel
            }
        )
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Pass it as constructor param in the `VoiceAdapters`
2. Create extension property:

```kotlin
   val View.lifecycleOwner get() = ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.get(this)`
```

then access it:  `parent.lifecycleOwner`

3. Resolve it only once:

```kotlin
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VoiceViewHolder {
       if(!::lifecycleOwner.isInitialized){
        lifecycleOwner = parent.context as LifecycleOwner
      }
}
```

They are pointing to the same `LifecycleOwner`, the `Context` that was used to inflate the layout.

`ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.get(view)` is convenient way to obtain the view's underlying `LifecycleOwner`. Therefore, my two cents go to option 1 or 2.

Comment: This is not working as expected and showing error while setting

Comment: The problem with this is the memory leak!

Answer (score -2):

If you're passing `context` in the Adapter through the constructor, you can get all the parameters related with that activity using `.` operator.